# Convert nested HashWithIndifferentAccess to nested Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Is there a nice way to transform an instance of a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` (with nested instances of class `HashWithIndifferentAccess`) to an instance of a Hash (with nested instances of class `Hash`)?

It seems easy to convert a nested `Hash` to a nested `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. Just use the `with_indifferent_access` method that ActiveSupport provides. This converts all hashes, no matter how deeply nested.

```
hash = { late: { package: 2, trial: 100, penalty: { amount: 1 } },
         no_show: { package: 1, trial: 100, penalty: { amount: 2 } } }
hash_wid = hash.with_indifferent_access
hash_wid.class
# ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess #great
hash_wid [:no_show][:penalty].class
# ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess #great
```

The reverse seems not so easy:

```
hash = hash_wid.to_h
hash.class
# Hash # OK
hash[:no_show][:penalty].class
# ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess # want this to be Hash
```

`Hash#to_h` method only converts the top level hash, not the nested hashes.

I tried the (Rails/ActiveSupport) `deep_transform_values!` method that extends the `Hash` class:

```
hash_wid.deep_transform_values! do |value|
  value.class == HashWithIndifferentAccess ? value.to_h : value
end
hash_wid.class
# ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess # want this to be Hash
hash_wid[:no_show][:penalty].class
# ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess # want this to be Hash
```

But looking to the source code of the `deep_transform_values!` method (and `transform_values!` method that it depends upon), these can transform hashes of class `Hash`, but not hashes of class `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

So is there a nice way to transform a nested `HashWithIndifferentAccess` to a nested `Hash`?

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: Why do you think you need this? (hint: use duck typing instead)

Comment: @max The context is an issue I had with a gem, rails-settings-cache, which I've raised here: https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached/issues/231.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example indicates that you are using keys and values whose types are compatible with JSON. If your hash can be converted to JSON then a simple way to do it is:

```rb
hash = JSON.load(JSON.dump({ foo: { bar: 'baz' }.with_indifferent_access }.with_indifferent_access))
=> {"foo"=>{"bar"=>"baz"}}

hash.class
=> Hash

hash['foo'].class
=> Hash
```

`deep_transform_values` won't work in your case because of [how that method is written](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_transform_values.rb#L27-L28):

```rb
    def _deep_transform_values_in_object(object, &block)
      case object
      when Hash
        object.transform_values { |value| _deep_transform_values_in_object(value, &block) }
      when Array
        object.map { |e| _deep_transform_values_in_object(e, &block) }
      else
        yield(object)
      end
    end
```

If your object is a Hash (or Array) then the method calls itself recursively until it finds a non-Hash and non-Array value onto which it can apply the transformation. It should be pretty trivial to write your own implementation using that example though:

```rb
    def _deep_transform_values_in_object(object, &block)
      case object
      when Hash
        # something less ugly than but similar to this
        object = object.to_h if object.is_a?(ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess)
        object.transform_values { |value| _deep_transform_values_in_object(value, &block) }
      when Array
        object.map { |e| _deep_transform_values_in_object(e, &block) }
      else
        yield(object)
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for both approaches @anothermh. I don’t think the first `.with_indifferent_access` in your example is needed, but I guess it makes it explicit.  The context of the question is a gem I have raised an issue with, which uses YAML, so I also came up with
`YAML.load(YAML.dump({ foo: { bar: 'baz' } }.with_indifferent_access).gsub('!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess',''))` which also seems to do the trick.

Comment: Correct, I just wanted to show explicit definitions being converted properly so there was no room for confusion. I'm not crazy about using gsub on a structured document but sometimes the quick fix is what's best for the problem. Glad it's working.